# Is multitouch gesture programming available in Delphi Firemonkey iOS apps?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

I am interested in using using Delphi XE2 to produce an iOS app. Is there currently any support for multitouch (2-3 finger swipes) using Firemonkey? If so, are there some references or samples available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, multitouch and gestures are not yet available in Firemonkey for iOS.

But: you can work around it, like [Anders Ohlsson showed](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/ao/2012/01/24/39201). He made the [modifications to Firemonkey available](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/28635) on Embarcadero [CodeCentral](http://cc.embarcadero.com).